# How can you always tell which direction does the arrow point?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

The task is simple (kinda hard for me, otherwise I wouldn't have to ask this question here), I have an image of label arrows like here below:

[image]

My steps are these:

1. Turn this image into into HSV

[image]

2. Blurr HSV image

[image]

3. Find mask based on HSV thresholds

[image]

4. Finding out the biggest contour

[image]

5. Doing a template matching by using this image

[image]

which produces this image

[image]

6. Drawing contours on this new image

[image]

7. Finding corners (red dots)

[image]

8. Finding center (yellow dot)

[image]

9. Finding a farthest point (cyan color)

[image]

The farthest point in this script should show the tip of the arrow, but as seen in this example, because of the reflections, the tip is actually not on the arrow itself but on the reflection's end. In this example since the tip of the arrow and the farhest point point to the same direction, it is correct that the answer for this arrow is "pointing downwards", but there are cases, where because of the reflections being part of the arrow contour, gives the incorrect prediction.

We have decided to use a solely a OpenCV solution (NO Machine Learning).

I was wondering if we could extract ONLY the arrow part without the reflections. About 90% of the arrows we extract have no reflections, but some produce reflections on arrows which drastically increases the margin of error. I want to somehow remove the reflections, because in that case the "farthest point algorithm" always tells the correct direction of the arrows.

Just as a side question, maybe there is a totally difference OpenCV (no machine learning used) solution which would produce 100% precision on these images?

Comment: can you avoid those reflections? light polarization filters can help

Comment: Don't blur the HSV image, blur the RGB image before conversion. The H channel is not continuous. Red is in a range around the discontinuity at 0, and averaging a bunch of red pixels could result in green. You don't have red pixels in your image, but it is still a good practice to use a suitable color space for each operation you perform.

Comment: How does the template matching not give you exactly where the arrow is and where it's pointing?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66718462/how-to-detect-different-types-of-arrows-in-image/